# When removing file from version control, how can it also be deleted from my local working directory?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

When I delete a file from TFS version control and "check-in" the change, the file still exists in my local working directory.

Is there a way I can get TFS or Visual Studio to clean-up after itself without having to manually deleting the files myself or changing my workspace to a different directory?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If I delete a file in TFS (2010), it deletes it straight away from my local drive (TFS shows a delete pending change), if I undo my pending change in TFS then the file reappears.

Are you deleting the file through the Solution Explorer or Team Explorer?